# Performing network calls in activity before creating fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to android development and I want to perform a network call of calling firebase database to fill array list with records. I want to create different fragment based on the object properties present in arraylist. Network calls take too much time, so what is the proper way to perform such task.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the steps you should do:

**In first time**:

In your Activity just run a background service that will fetch the list of Objects. After fetching list you store the list item's in local storage like shared preferences or database. After saving data you open your fragment.

**After First Time:**

Check is there you have saved list item? if list contains data then directly open your desired fragment. At the same time you update the list items using service call.

Here is some related links:

1. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm
2. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Hope this will help you.